# Can't set state in react to array of strings

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm new to react and having a super hard time.  My most recent problem is trying to set the state of 'favMovies' to an array of strings (movie IDs).

States:

```
export class MainView extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movies: [],
      favMovies: [],
      user: null,
    };
  }
```

Setting states:

```
onLoggedIn(authData) {
    console.log(authData);
    console.log(authData.user.FavoriteMovies);
    this.setState({
      favMovies: authData.user.FavoriteMovies,
    });
    this.setState({ user: authData.user });
    localStorage.setItem('token', authData.token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(authData.user));
    this.getMovies(authData.token);
    this.getUsers();
  }
```

I kind of understand that set state is async and doesn't happen until the next render.  The part that I'm confused by is the 'user' that get's set after 'favMovies' works as expected, but 'favMovies' is undefined.

I know this is probly a dumb question, but I'm absolutely lost in react right now and struggling.
  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not set favMovies and user at one go? Also since favMovies is included in the user object, i dont think you should store it again. Just use user.favMovies directly.

Comment: What this code block `this.getMovies(authData.token);
    this.getUsers();` are doing? Are those fetching data from backend?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath yes, this is the client side of an app with an api.

Comment: @B33Gs so is this `this.getMovies(authData.token);` fetching movie data by user token?

Comment: @ajay I forgot I could do that.  It's implemented now.    This is a small part of me trying to figure out a larger problem.   I need 'FavoriteMovies' displayed by titles and not the IDs that are stored as said favorites.  I can't map these inside of render, or the app breaks.  the only thing I could think to do is make them into a state so i can pass them into the other component and map them in the methods.  but I'm super lost in React, so that's probly a bad idea too.

Answer (score 0):

It's alaways better to use single setState if possible, because everytime you call setState it will re-render the view. One more tip for you, when you are dealing with object and arrays try to use spread operstor to assign to the state, instead of direct assignment.

```
onLoggedIn(authData) {
    console.log(authData);
    console.log(authData.user.FavoriteMovies);
    this.setState({
      favMovies: [...authData.user.FavoriteMovies],
user: authData.user 
    });
    //this.setState({ user: authData.user });
    localStorage.setItem('token', authData.token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(authData.user));
   this.getMovies(authData.token);
    this.getUsers();
  }
```

As we know react setState is asynchronous, state won't reflect immediately. We can use callback with setState where we can access updated state.

```
this.setState(
    {
        favMovies: [...authData.user.FavoriteMovies],
        user: authData.user 
        // ...
    },    
    () => {
        this.doSomethingAfterStateUpdate(); 
    }
);
```

Comment: I will definitely utilize this moving forward.  Thank you.  It didn't fix the problem, but I think I just need to figure out a different way to go about the larger issue I'm working on.   I really do appreciate your help.  Thank you again!

Comment: I have edited the answer which might be helpful for you. Let me know if it helps with your use case.

Comment: I ended up going with something a little simpler.  I didn't realize I could just set it equal to the newly created array, so I went with that.  I ended up solving the other part of the issue I was running into as well.  I really appreciate both you reaching out and checking back.  I was super down earlier and your help picked me back up.  So sincerely, thank you!

Comment: I believe it is not good practice to modify state directly, this will lead to bugs which are hard to find. If your state is not meant to update view/ child components then don't use it, instead use local scope. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: I have a separate component (user-view) that will display the list of movie names.  The code I've shown is in the main component (main-view).   The issue is, user.FavoriteMovies is a list of movie IDs.  I need to cross reference it with the movies-list, which I'm doing with map functions, to get movie names from the IDs.  I can access user.FavoriteMovies and the movies list as props in user-view (in render(){}), but if I try to map there, it breaks the app.  My only solution is to do it inside the componendDidUpdate() in the main view.  I'm sure there's a better way, but I don't know it.

Comment: I'm open to any suggestions you might have. :)